# Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Bool'

Tags: swift

Why I can't use c? 1 : 2 syntax in swiftui? 
Is there any solution?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var c: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
          .foregroundColor(c? .red : .blue)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the ternary operation correctly you need to put a space between the `c` and the `?`

```
.foregroundColor(c ? .red : .blue)
```

You can see more [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID71), in the Swift docs under **Ternary Conditional Operator**